# How to pause the script until user input happens

Tags: javascript

I'm making a connect four game.
When a human player plays the game I want him to be able to click on the column he wants to make his move in.

I'm struggeling with the addition of events to the columns that are legal to make a move into.
The following code shall return an item from `legalMoves` based on which column the player clicks. As long as no click on a legal column is happening, the code should pause and just wait.

Right now, it seems like the lines with `addEventListeners` are just ignored, the code just keeps running and doesnt wait for human input.

```
// array of legal moves, eg.[0,1,3,5,6]
let legalMoves = game.getLegalMoves();

// initialization with -1 to check if it changes
let humanMove = -1;

//column nodes
let node = document.getElementsByClassName("column");

// my try of getting at least the first column to work
node[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
                    humanMove = 0;
});
/* pseudo code:
while(humanmove===-1){
wait here until one event listener fires
}*/
// returns -1 every time :'(
return humanMove;
```

Comment: You can just add if statement where you check is `humanMove == -1` after event listener declaration and depend on that you decide what will happen next

Comment: I don't get the need for the while loop. Why don't you do whatever you intend to do (maybe call a function with a specific parameter) in the click eventlistener itself?

Comment: @Leguest Do you mean what I wrote in the pseudocode? What could I put in the braces?

Comment: @jrook because this is a part of a switch, and every case has to return a move, like here. i have done this for a random player already for example, who just returns a random item of the legalMoves array. but for the human player, i want to chose by mouse clicks on the columns

Comment: @Tweakimp, I see. But you can use `this` to pass information to your event handler and then call another function (to respond to move or do something else) with that parameter. I don't think your current implementation can ever work since the while loop effectively traps the program in an infinite loop.

Comment: Continually running your while loop until some value changes is practically the same as an infinite loop:  it could crash the browser. Use an event handler: wait for a click, then determine if the click is legal or not, and do what needs to be done. If your code is part of a switch: post it and maybe somebody will have a suggestion on how to deal with it.

Comment: One other way that might work is to use [promises](http://caniuse.com/#search=promises)

Comment: One callback for player, one callback for cpu. When function is called it passes whatever data is returned from the opponent's callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would have preferred if the OP had provided the HTML for "game" and had defined the method getLegalMoves(), I modified the code, making one especially important change.  Note, I'm unsure why the OP uses "let" to define variables in the global scope when they are not contained within a code block, i.e. defined with braces.  That said, here's a modified version that works.  The critical change involved getting rid of the return statement, since JavaScript only permits returning a value from a function or method.

HTML:

```
<div id="game">
<div class="column">
<button>Test</button>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column {
    color:blue;
}
```

JS:

```
// array of legal moves, eg.[0,1,3,5,6]
//let legalMoves = game.getLegalMoves();

// initialization with -1 to check if it changes
let humanMove = -1;

//column nodes
var node = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
node[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  humanMove = 0;
  console.log(humanMove);
});
```

working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pn1fcv2y/5/)